# Github api v3 access via python oauth2 library - Redirect issue

Tags: python, github, web.py

Environment - Python 2.7.3, webpy.

I'm trying a simple oauth 3 way authentication for github using Python web.py. Per the basic oauth guide on github I'm doing something like this:

```
import web,requests
import oauth2,pymongo,json
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
urls=('/', 'githublogin',
      '/session','session',
      '/githubcallback','githubCallback');
class githublogin:
  def GET(self):
    new_url = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize'
    pay_load = {'client_id': '',
                'client_secret':'',
                'scope':'gist'
               }
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.get(new_url, params=pay_load, headers=headers)
    return r.content
```

This is sending me to the GH login page. Once I sign in - GH is not redirecting me to the callback. The redirect_uri parameter is configured in the github application. I've double checked to make sure that's correct.

```
 class githubCallback:
   def POST(self):
     data =  web.data()
     print data
   def GET(self):
     print "callback called"
```

Instead in the browser I see 
`http://<hostname>:8080/session` 
and a 404 message, because I haven't configured the session URL. That's problem no 1. Problem no 2 - If I configure the session URL and print out the post message

```
class session:
  def POST(self):
    data =  web.data()
      print data
    def GET(self):
      print "callback called"
```

I can see some data posted to the URL with something called 'authenticity_token'.

I've tried to use the python_oauth2 library but can't get past the authorization_url call. So I've tried this much simpler requests library. Can someone please point out to me whats going wrong here.

Comment: Is this the guide you are following: http://developer.github.com/guides/basics-of-authentication/ ? What is this "session" you are writing about? Is this the callback or something else? Also, you don't need to send the client secret on the initial request, you just send the client id and scope, and optionally the redirect url: http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#web-application-flow. You send the client secret on the second request, from within your callback handler.

Comment: @IvanZuzak - Here's the dev guide Im using `http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#web-application-flow`

Comment: @IvanZuzak Sorry hit enter too soon  Here's the dev guide Im using `http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#web-application-flow`        I triend sending the request without the client_secret. Same result. The '/session' is the URL that I see in the browser after I enter the github username password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is at your end, but try reproducing this flow below, first manually using the browser, and then using your python library. It will help you debug the issue.

1. create a request bin on http://requestb.in/. A request bin is basically a service that logs all HTTP requests sent to it. You will use this instead of the callback, to log what is being sent to the callback. Copy the URL of the request bin, which is something like http://requestb.in/123a546b
2. Go to your OAuth application setup on GitHub (https://github.com/settings/applications), enter the setup of your specific application, and set the Callback URL to the URL of the request bin you just created.
3. Make a request to the GitHub OAuth page, with the client_id defined. Just enter this URL below into your browser, but change the YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE to be the client id of your OAuth application:

   `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE`
4. Enter your username and password and click Authorize. The GitHub app will then redirect you to the request bin service you created, and the URL in the browser should be something like (notice the code query parameter):

   `http://requestb.in/YOUR_REQUEST_BIN_ID?code=GITHUB_CODE`

   (for example, `http://requestb.in/abc1def2?code=123a456b789cdef`)

   Also, the content of the page in the browser should be "ok" (this is the content returned by the request bin service).
5. Go to the request bin page that you created and refresh it. You will now see a log entry for the HTTP GET request that the GitHub OAuth server sent you, together with all the HTTP headers. Basically, you will see there the same code parameter that is present in the URL that you were redirected to. If you get this parameter, you are now ready to make a POST request with this code and your client secret, as described in step 2 of the guide you are using: http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#web-application-flow

Let me know if any of these steps are causing problems for you.

Comment: This flow works perfect. I'm doing pretty much the same in the python flow and it's crapping. Thanks for the inputs. I'll see whats going wrong with the Python library.

Comment: That's really strange. I suggest you also try using either a normal Python HTTP library to send HTTP request as you would to through the browser (e.g. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) or use a Python library for GitHub which usually correctly handle OAuth flows (http://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/#python). In any case, let us know when you find out what was bugging you :).

Comment: I was using python requests library. However this time I made a simple change. Instead of sending the login request from the server, I sent it from a html page, rendered using templates. That worked. I'm going to elaborate further in the answer section.

Answer (score 3):

So here's how I solved this. Thanks to @Ivanzuzak for the requestb.in tip.

I'm using Python webpy.

```
import web,requests
import oauth2,json
urls=('/', 'githublogin',
      '/githubcallback','githubCallback');
render = web.template.render('templates/')
class githublogin:
  def GET(self):
    client_id = ''
    url_string = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + client_id
    return render.index(url_string)

class githubCallback:
  def GET(self):
    data =  json.loads(json.dumps(web.input()))
    print data['code']
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    pay_load = {'client_id': '',
                'client_secret':'',
                'code' : data['code'] }
    r = requests.post('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token',  data=json.dumps(pay_load), headers=headers)
    token_temp = r.text.split('&')
    token = token_temp[0].split('=')
    access_token = token[1]
    repo_url = 'https://api.github.com/user?access_token=' + access_token
    response = requests.get(repo_url)
    final_data = response.content
    print final_data

app = web.application(urls,globals())
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

I was not using a html file before, but sending the request directly from the githublogin class. That didn't work. Here I'm using a html to direct the user first from where he'll login to gh. With this I added a html and rendered it using the templator.

```
def with (parameter)
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Well, hello there!</p>
    <p>We're going to now talk to the GitHub API. Ready? <a href=$parameter>Click here</a> to begin!</a></p>
    <p>If that link doesn't work, remember to provide your own <a href="http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#web-application-flow">Client ID</a>!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This file is taken straight from the dev guide, with just the client_id parameter changed.

Another point to be noted is that in the requests.post method - passing the pay_load directly doesn't work. It has to be serialized using json.dumps.